# Str object is not callable TypeError for Connect four game using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror, function-call

I'm practicing Python by making a connect four game and I've got stuck at this error and I'm not sure what next steps I should take to fix it.
File "main.py", line 108, in 
player1()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])

print(df)

a = df['A']
b = df['B']
c = df['C']
d = df['D']
e = df['E']
f = df['F']

player1 = 'H'
player2 = 'X'

for i in range(len(df)):
  a_cell = a[i]
  b_cell = b[i]
  c_cell = c[i]
  d_cell = d[i]
  e_cell = e[i]
  f_cell = f[i]

  # Prevents board piece from changing after changed once
  if a[i] == 'X' or a[i] == 'H':
    a[i] != player1.inputs or player2.inputs
  if b[i] == 'X' or b[i] == 'H':
    b[i] != player1.inputs or player2.inputs
  if c[i] == 'X' or c[i] == 'H':
    c[i] != player1.inputs or player2.inputs
  if d[i] == 'X' or d[i] == 'H':
    d[i] != player1.inputs or player2.inputs
  if e[i] == 'X' or e[i] == 'H':
    e[i] != player1.inputs or player2.inputs
  if f[i] == 'X' or f[i] == 'H':
    f[i] != player1.inputs or player2.inputs  

# Places board pieces from input
def player1():

  if player1 == "a" and a[i] != "X" and a[i] != "H":
    a[i] = "H"
    print(df)

  elif player1 == "b" and b[i] != 'X' and b[i] != 'H':
    b[i] = "H"
    print(df)

  elif player1 == "c" and c[i] != 'X' and b[i] != 'H':
    c[i] = "H"
    print(df)

  elif player1 == "d" and d[i] != 'X' and b[i] != 'H':
    d[i] = "H"
    print(df)

  elif player1 == "e" and e[i] != 'X' and b[i] != 'H':
    e[i] = "H"
    print(df)

  elif player1 == "f" and f[i] != 'X' and b[i] != 'H':
    f[i] = "H"
    print(df)

  else:
    player1 = input("Player1, select a correct board piece: ")
    player1()

def player2():    

  if player2 == "a" and a[i] != "X" and a[i] != "H":
    a[i] = "X"
    print(df)

  elif player2 == "b" and b[i] != 'X' and b[i] != 'H':
    b[i] = 'X'
    print(df)

  elif player2 == "c" and c[i] != 'X' and c[i] != 'H':
    c[i] = "X"
    print(df)

  elif player2 == "d" and d[i] != 'X' and d[i] != 'H':
    d[i] = "X"
    print(df)

  elif player2 == "e" and e[i] != 'X' and e[i] != 'H' :
    e[i] = "X"
    print(df)

  elif player2 == "f" and f[i] != 'X' and f[i] != 'H':
    f[i] = "X"
    print(df)

  else:
    player2 = input("Player2, select a correct board piece: ")
    player2()

player1 = "H"
player2 = "X"
player1 = input("Player1, select board piece: ")
while True:

  if player1 == 'a' or player1 == 'b' or player1 == 'c' or player1 == 'd' or player1 == 'e' or 
  player1 == 'f':
    player1()
    player2 = input("Player2, select board piece: ")


  elif player2 == 'a' or player2 == 'b' or player2 == 'c' or player2 == 'd' or player2 == 'e' or 
  player2 == 'f':
    player2()
    player1 = input("Player1, select board piece: ")
```

It also says local variable 'player1' defined in enclosing scope on line 114 referenced before assignment and there's one for 'player2' but on line 109

Comment: You should have dict of dataframes, so that you can simply access `dfs[player1][i]` rather than use a giant `if` statement to select the correct dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will have to look into having a dict for dataframes

Comment: Do either of the posted answers help? If not, how can they be improved?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same name for a function and a string. First, you define functions called `player1` and `player2`. Then, on line 105, you assign a string to the variable `player1` when you capture the text from `input`. So, when you then try to call `player1()` on line 110, you get an error because a string cannot be called.

Note that you need to fix this error for `player2` as well. You also repeat the same error in the function definitions themselves, where you are calling the functions `player1` and `player2` recursively after defining those variables as strings.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1:** `TypeError`

You set `player1` to a string at first, then define a function called `player1`, then define `player1` as a string again (with `input`), then try to call `player1` (which at the time of trying to call is a string). Try coming up with different names for the functions, like `move_player1` or something (I'll use this name in the second part of this answer).

**Issue 2:** `UnboundLocalError`

As for variable referenced before assignment, you're getting this because, while you define `player1` outside of `move_player1`, scoping rules in Python make a new `player1` variable (local variable) if `player1` is (re)defined within `move_player1`. Thus you can't reference the outer `player1` and reassign it in this manner. The simplest way to fix this would be to declare `player1` as global.

For example:

```py
player1 = "H"

def move_player1():
    global player1
    # ... rest of function
```

Though you might also consider just passing `player1` as an argument to `move_player1` and move its definition (using `input`) outside of `move_player1`.